# Convert Query Having mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to convert this query  to Laravel

```
SELECT COUNT(uplineNetworkdetail) AS uplineNetworkdetailCount
               , idNetworkdetail
               , uplineNetworkdetail
               , downlineNetworkdetail
             FROM networkdetailCommunity where uplineNetworkdetail <>'0'
             GROUP BY uplineNetworkdetail
             HAVING uplineNetworkdetailCount = '1'
             ORDER BY posisi asc
```

please help me how to do that ?

Comment: stack overflow is not code service place

Answer (score 0):

The Query will be :

```
$query = DB::table('networkdetailCommunity')
     ->select('DB::RAW(COUNT(uplineNetworkdetail) AS uplineNetworkdetailCount)','idNetworkdetail','uplineNetworkdetail','downlineNetworkdetail')
     ->where('uplineNetworkdetail','<>','0')
     ->groupBy('uplineNetworkdetail')
     ->havingRaw("uplineNetworkdetailCount='1'")
     ->orderBy('posisi')
     ->get();
```

Comment: ty.. god bless u